# memory cashe for uploading image to android

Tags: android, image

Can somebody please kindly explain this code to me. I don't fully understand this. it is for creating a memory cashe for uploading image..
In particular, I would like to know
* 1. What is softReference
* 2. What is containsKey
* 3. Is the softReference stored in memory cashe
* 4. Why Cashe is a synchronizedMap (cache=Collections.synchronizedMap)

Thank you very much

```
package com.androidhive.imagefromurl; 

import java.lang.ref.SoftReference; 
import java.util.Collections; 
import java.util.HashMap; 
import java.util.Map; 
import android.graphics.Bitmap; 

public class MemoryCache { 
private Map<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> cache=Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String,   SoftReference<Bitmap>>()); 

public Bitmap get(String id){ 
    if(!cache.containsKey(id)) 
        return null; 
    SoftReference<Bitmap> ref=cache.get(id); 
    return ref.get(); 
} 

public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap){ 
    cache.put(id, new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bitmap)); 
} 

public void clear() { 
    cache.clear(); 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should read the documentations first, and then come back here with your specific questions.

[SoftReference documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html)

[containsKey method from Map Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29)

[synchronizedMap (Map map) documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%3CK,%20V%3E%29)